# How to change data of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Considering the following JavaScript code that runs in Node.js is there any way to change the input data according to below statements ?

Since I am a newbie in JS I do not understand if it passes the header meaning pointer or a value .

- u_new = u cos(v)
- v_new = u sin(v)

```
    setData (data) {
    if (data.length > 1) {
      this.u.data = data[0].data
      this.v.data = data[1].data
      this._baseLayer.setData([this.u , this.v])
      Layer.prototype.setData.call(this, data)
    }
  },
  setModel (model) {
    let modelHeader = {
      ...
    }
    Object.assign(this.u.header, modelHeader)
    Object.assign(this.v.header, modelHeader)
    Layer.prototype.setModel.call(this, model)
  }
```

Original inputs u and v are arrays in this format :

This is u data array

```
["NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN",0.77,0.76,0.75,0.84,0.94,1.03,1.11,"NaN"]
```

This is v data array

Note that v values are in degrees while JavaScript's Math read radians.

```
["NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN",187.21,189.48,190.58,192.54,194.48,"NaN",197.21,198.09]
```

I have already tried the following without any success, I can't see any animation running (I animate u-v vectors)  :

```
// radians = degrees * PI / 180
this.u.data = data[0].data * Math.cos(data[1].data * Math.PI / 180) 
this.v.data = data[0].data * Math.sin(data[1].data * Math.PI / 180)
```

If such a data processing is not possible should I modify the arrays before I pass them as input to JS ?

Comment: "without any success" - what does that mean? console errors? Calculation errors?

Comment: @ mplungjan You are right sir, sorry for not noting what I mean. I just updated the question. I animate u & v vector data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
const uRads = ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 0.77, 0.76, 0.75, 0.84, 0.94, 1.03, 1.11, "NaN"]
  .map(deg => deg === "NaN" ? 0 : Math.cos(deg * Math.PI / 180))

const vRads = ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 187.21, 189.48, 190.58, 192.54, 194.48, "NaN", 197.21, 198.09]
  .map(deg => deg === "NaN" ? 0 : Math.cos(deg * Math.PI / 180))


const res = uRads.map((urad, i) => console.log(urad, vRads[i]))
```

Comment: u and v json are not only 2 specific files, so they can't be const, there are multiple with 1 - 1 ratio which are loaded by a server folder.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. You can do `this.u.data = ["NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN",187.21,189.48,190.58,192.54,194.48,"NaN",197.21,198.09].map(deg =>
deg === "NaN" ? 0 : Math.cos(deg * Math.PI / 180))` if that is what you need

Comment: OR you can do `this.u.data = uArray.map(deg =>
deg === "NaN" ? 0 : Math.cos(deg * Math.PI / 180))` if you have the array in a var

Comment: @ mplungjan That works fine, thank you very much. How can I multiply u_new = u cos v ? That's my cos v = data[1].map(deg => deg === "NaN" ? 0 : Math.cos(deg * Math.PI / 180))

Comment: See update. Change console.log for whatever you need to do

Comment: @mgplungjan Yes thank you , but how can I multiply two arrays ? Let's say data[0].data × data[1].data map(deg => deg === "NaN" ? 0 : Math.cos(deg * Math.PI / 180)) ?

Comment: Sorry that is just math - that is up to you. I have zero idea what you are trying to do so I just made it possible for you to do whatever it is you need to do

Comment: Consider that data[0].data is an array with float numbers and data[1].data map(deg => deg === "NaN" ? 0 : Math.cos(deg * Math.PI / 180)) is also an array with float numbers with the same dimension. How can I multiply this two arrays ? I have tried already Math.dot but didn't work . Do you have any idea ? Sorry for not giving more info sooner ..

Comment: Perhaps `const res = uRads.map((urad, i) => urad * vRads[i]); console.log(res)` I have not seen a cosine in more than π decades